# In /etc/hosts is there something special about the first hostname for any given line?

Tags: linux, unix, hosts, fqdn

I know that the first one is said to be *canonical*, but I don't fully understand the practical implications. This question was triggered by the man page for **hostname -f**, specifically when it says:

```
Technically: The FQDN is the name gethostbyname(2)
returns for the host name returned by gethostname(2).
The DNS domain name is the part after the first dot.
```

Let's assume that the computer hostname is **foo**.

With the following configuration:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       foo.example.com    foo
```

The command **hostname -f** returns **foo.example.com**.

While, with the following configuration:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       foo    foo.example.com
```

The command **hostname -f** returns **foo**.

**Specifically, is the first hostname what man calls 'the official name of the host' when talking about hostent.h_name?**

**Note**: I'm on Debian but hopefully these concepts are of general *nix interest.

**Link**: A [possibly related](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name) question.

**Link**: [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/331475/does-not-having-fqdn-in-etc-hosts-cause-any-problems?rq=1) suggests that the second style is wrong, nevertheless I've seen it applied several times around the web.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to me what is actually left to be answered. You seem to have already noted that the first name is the canonical/official name, how it is used and what effect it has.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, the first entry is the canonical (official) name, where all subsequent names are just aliases to the first. In my experience (in a typical prod environment), /etc/hosts looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost
10.0.0.1    myhostname.domain.tld myhostname
```